# startActivity cannot start another activty without any exception

Tags: android, android-activity

My application got crash when tried to call startActivity(intent) to start new activity. But there is no any exception in LogCat. Is there any best way to catch the root cause?

Comment: post your code and logcat message here

Comment: did you declared your `Activity` in `Manifest` file

Comment: Declare activity in menifest with proper path, check layout file for error, Last debug your activity so that you can check from which line app got crash.

Comment: `there is no any exception in LogCat` I don't believe that. look once more carefully.

Answer (score -2):

Use fabric to know the cause of your crash.